# Spring Cloud Data Flow Design

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have an existing process that I am trying to convert into SCDF implementation. The current process is,

HTTP Receiver (receive HTTP POST data) -> RabbitMQ -> MQ Receiver Service -> Process/Transform -> DB Sink

How can I achieve such flow, if possible? (1st issue)

So far, I figured that SCDF supports producer -> process -> consumer flow only.

I also tried to create multiple flows (HTTP Source -> RabbitMQ Sink & RabbitMQ Source -> Process -> DB) but deployment of RabbitMQ (as source and sink) does not work on Cloud Foundry (2nd issue). Aperently, I can deploy a stream with either Rabbit source or sink but not both togather (even as different stream).

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described is the fundamental streaming pipeline using `named` destinations and it is expected to work including Cloud Foundry environment.
You can check out this [sample](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/streams/named-destinations/) for more information.
If you still see the issue, please share the exact error/exception while you try deploy the streams.